# Getting appropriate UITableViewCell separations: GUI

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I have a `UITableViewController` that is segue-embedded with a `UIContainerView`. I'm having trouble appropriating the spacings located between the three given `UITableViewCell`'s.

[image]

-- I need another space above the very top cell and between the 2nd and 3rd `UITableViewCell`, I'm having a hard time finding out how to accomplish this.

Answer (score 1):

In your `UITableViewDelegate`, add this following method:

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

From there you can control the total height of each cell independently. Don't do this for large tables, however, as it slows things down.

If you are not using section headers (or footers) already, you can use them to add arbitrary spacing to table cells. Instead of having one section with n rows, create a table with n sections with one row each.

Implement the `tableView:heightForHeaderInSection:` method to control the spacing.

You may also want to implement `tableView:viewForHeaderInSection:` to control what the spacing looks like.